# what does Ctrl + PLUS/MINUS do in modern browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

From my understanding, the best way for increasing text size is using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>. This also keeps the layout. But does anyone know what exactly browsers do when this key combination is pressed? I want to make sure my layout isn't

I've seen many websites (even Google and Amazon) have problems with this zooming, as the divs start to overlay each other and text gets messy. This is mostly visible on websites that do not have a fixed width body.

edit: I want to know what exactly happens: How are elements and divs with no fixed width handled? Does the html div width change to? Do elements change in the same proportion etc...
I think there is a clear specification since all browsers seem to show similar results when zooming in and out.

Comment: People that DO use these features for accessibility, are very prepared for the consequences. They don't care how pretty your website is after manually increasing the font size, so long as it's usable. Their primary concern is READING your website, not the aesthetics of doing so

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> Zooms the browser in, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> zooms the browser out.

[Documentation](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/font-size-and-zoom-increase-size-of-web-pages)

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers have certain shortcuts that they share. Among these are the two you mention: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

When used, these keystrokes allow the user to zoom in and zoom out, respectively. Similarly, if you hold control and scroll your mouse wheel up and down (respectively), you will get the same behavior.

Mind you, this doesn't just increase/decrease the size of the text, it magnifies (or zooms out) all the content on the page including images, banners, etc.

As a developer, if you wants to create a responsive layout to deal with zoomed in web pages, you should avoid using fixed units like `pixels` and use units such as `percentages` and `em`.

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114518/47-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-in-all-web-browsers/) is a list of keyboard shortcuts shared by most common browsers.

Comment: It used to change just the size of the text in older versions of certain browsers.

Comment: Please look at the edit.
I know what it does, I want to know how it handles the elements.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on what browser we are discussing. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+/-</kbd> zooms the browser in/out. Some browsers, like Firefox, allows you to only increase the text size via View > Zoom > Zoom Text Only. This leaves things like `<div>`s in place, until the size is too large and [pixel-perfect] layouts, collapse. IE has a similar option, which is found via View > Text Size, which operates kind of the same as Firefox's, but not totally and a limited scope. I thought Opera had this functionality too, but it was removed from the looks of it.

Then, as other answers mention, you get into what units the site in question uses. Mixing fixed and relative units makes what, when and how an element zooms a bit more complicated.

Comment: It actually depends whether the website has a defined font size or not. If yes, I think all browsers ignore any changes of the font size via the view> text size menu.

Comment: If the font size is not defined, it defaults to `font-size:100%` or `1em`, which are the same

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers (Firefox 3.x+, Chrome 2.x+, IE 7+) use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> shortcuts for a full-page zoom. The way that each rendering engine handles this process is slightly different, but generally as long as you don't have anything aligned from the right or the bottom, it should not cause many issues.

If you mix fixed and relative units however (`px`/`pt` with `%`/`em`/`ex`), they *can* scale differently, causing the various elements to shift out of their original proportions.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design for methods to handle various viewport sizes.